# Failed connection to Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, keyboard

I am having great difficulty getting my Android App to connect to an Amazon Basics Bluetooth Keyboard. I can pair the keyboard with the Android device manually, no problem. However, doing it programmatically fails. The App successfully recognises the device as an Amazon Basic Keyboard and gets the MAC address, it just won't connect. I have tried running the code on 2 different Android devices (one running 2.3.3; the other 4.0.3), but the result is the same.

Trying the documented method (code fragment):

```
private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("b1b9aee2-a388-11e4-89d3-123b93f75cba"); // I generated this UUID

...

tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
tmp.connect();
```

This fails with:

**java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed**

I've also tried using various "standard" UUIDs such as 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB, 00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB with the same error. I am also cancelling Device Discovery before trying to connect.

I have also tried the undocumented method (code fragment):

```
BluetoothSocket socket;
Method m;
m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",new Class[] { int.class });
socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
socket.connect();
```

This also fails, but with a different error:

**java.io.IOException: Connection refused**

I have tried both these methods with the device paired and unpaired with the same results. I also resorted to an unlikely Thread.sleep(5000) before connecting without success. After several days trying I'm at a loss as to what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Colin

**Update 28/02/2015**: This is clearly a difficult issue to resole. To try and help I am posting the full log output from one of my runs to see if this can help.

```
02-28 11:06:22.721: I/ActivityStack(201): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 pkg=com.example.bluetoothtest cmp=com.example.bluetoothtest/.MainActivity} from pid 547
02-28 11:06:22.721: V/ActivityStack(201): Prepare open transition: starting ActivityRecord{41a90e60 com.example.bluetoothtest/.MainActivity}
02-28 11:06:22.768: V/ActivityStack(201): Prepare open transition: prev=ActivityRecord{41a972d0 com.amazon.kindle.otter/.Launcher}
02-28 11:06:22.775: D/bluetooth2(996): ...Bluetooth ON...
02-28 11:06:22.775: D/bluetooth2(996): ...onResume - try connect...
02-28 11:06:22.775: D/bluetooth2(996): Socket Created!
02-28 11:06:22.775: D/BluetoothService.cpp(201): stopDiscoveryNative
02-28 11:06:22.775: E/BluetoothService.cpp(201): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
02-28 11:06:22.775: D/bluetooth2(996): ...Connecting...
02-28 11:06:22.775: D/BluetoothService.cpp(201): createDeviceNative
02-28 11:06:22.775: D/BluetoothService.cpp(201): ... address = 90:7F:61:97:AE:BE
02-28 11:06:22.783: D/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(201): onCreateDeviceResult
02-28 11:06:22.783: D/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(201): ... Address = 90:7F:61:97:AE:BE
02-28 11:06:22.783: E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(201): onCreateDeviceResult: D-Bus error: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists (Already Exists)
02-28 11:06:22.783: D/BluetoothEventLoop(201): Result of onCreateDeviceResult:1
02-28 11:06:22.783: D/BluetoothService.cpp(201): discoverServicesNative
02-28 11:06:22.783: D/BluetoothService.cpp(201): ... Object Path = /org/bluez/121/hci0/dev_90_7F_61_97_AE_BE
02-28 11:06:22.783: D/BluetoothService.cpp(201): ... Pattern = , strlen = 0
02-28 11:06:22.783: I//system/bin/bluetoothd(110): bluetoothd[121]: external/bluetooth/bluez/src/device.c:btd_device_ref() 0x1e90a88: ref=3
02-28 11:06:22.924: D/dalvikvm(201): GC_EXPLICIT freed 415K, 21% free 21196K/26503K, paused 3ms+9ms
02-28 11:06:23.455: I//system/bin/bluetoothd(110): bluetoothd[121]: external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:conn_complete() status 0x00
02-28 11:06:23.471: D/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(201): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/121/hci0/dev_90_7F_61_97_AE_BE
02-28 11:06:23.471: D/BluetoothEventLoop(201): Device property changed: 90:7F:61:97:AE:BE property: Connected value: true
02-28 11:06:23.479: I//system/bin/bluetoothd(110): bluetoothd[121]: external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:remote_features_information() hci0 status 0
02-28 11:06:23.479: I//system/bin/bluetoothd(110): bluetoothd[121]: external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:remote_name_information() hci0 status 0
02-28 11:06:23.682: I//system/bin/bluetoothd(110): bluetoothd[121]: external/bluetooth/bluez/src/device.c:search_cb() 90:7F:61:97:AE:BE: No service update
02-28 11:06:23.682: D/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(201): onDiscoverServicesResult
02-28 11:06:23.682: D/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(201): ... Device Path = /org/bluez/121/hci0/dev_90_7F_61_97_AE_BE
02-28 11:06:23.682: D/BluetoothService.cpp(201): getDevicePropertiesNative
02-28 11:06:23.682: I//system/bin/bluetoothd(110): bluetoothd[121]: external/bluetooth/bluez/src/device.c:btd_device_unref() 0x1e90a88: ref=2
02-28 11:06:23.689: D/BluetoothService(201): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(90:7F:61:97:AE:BE)
02-28 11:06:23.689: D/BluetoothService(201): Cleaning up failed UUID channel lookup: 90:7F:61:97:AE:BE 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
02-28 11:06:23.689: D/bluetooth2(996): ....Connection failed...
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996): java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:397)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:207)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at com.example.bluetoothtest.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:138)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1154)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4711)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2516)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2562)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2065)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1181)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4558)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-28 11:06:23.689: W/System.err(996):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 11:06:23.791: I/ActivityManager(201): Displayed com.example.bluetoothtest/.MainActivity: +1s23ms
02-28 11:06:24.814: V/Sensors(201): accel data: 0.028740 0.076641 9.091495
02-28 11:06:28.088: I//system/bin/bluetoothd(110): bluetoothd[121]: external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:disconn_complete() handle 12 status 0x00
02-28 11:06:28.088: I//system/bin/bluetoothd(110): bluetoothd[121]: external/bluetooth/bluez/src/event.c:btd_event_disconn_complete() 
02-28 11:06:28.088: I//system/bin/bluetoothd(110): bluetoothd[121]: external/bluetooth/bluez/src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection() 
02-28 11:06:28.088: D/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(201): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/121/hci0/dev_90_7F_61_97_AE_BE
02-28 11:06:28.088: D/BluetoothEventLoop(201): Device property changed: 90:7F:61:97:AE:BE property: Connected value: false
```